# How to get a config value into a href as string instead of object object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I have a config file setup that exports a bunch of values...

```
const dev = {
    ...,
    someRandomLink: 'https://google.com'
}
const config = process.env.REACT_APP_STAGE === 'production' ? prod : dev;
export default {
   ...config
}
```

I then import this file and try to use the value for a href but it outputs `[Object object]`.

```
import someRandomLink from '../constants/config';


...
<a href={someRandomLink}...
```

What is the correct way to extract that config variable as a string for the link?

Comment: The variable `someRandomLink` is an object. If you do a `console.log(someRandomLink)` step in your component, you will see what is the correct path for the desired property which is containing the link itself. Then you can pass it to `href`.

Answer (score 3):

You are exporting an object that contains `someRandomLink` as property.

When you import the default export, you are importing the entire object and giving it a name, instead of import the specific property.

Try to use it like this

```js
import { someRandomLink } from '../constants/config';

...
<a href={someRandomLink}...
```

or like this is possible as well:

```js
import config from '../constants/config';

...
<a href={config.someRandomLink}...
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
export default {
   ...config
}
```

So you are trying to export as default an object (I guess it's not config, it's `dev`).
There's 2 ways to export some info from a file:

1) `export default myFunction` this is importing one single method/object/any value you want to do. Then to import it it's as easy as `import myFunction from './myFile'`. Since it's a default export, you could name it as you wish: `import Hello from './myFile'` would work as well.

2) `export {myFunction}` this is the way to import it as a module, and not a default. With this technique you can import multiple functions like `export {myFunction, myOtherFunction, myAwesomeThirdFunction}`. The way to import it then it's like `import {myFunction} from './myFile'`.

In your case you have a mixup between default and the module exports. My suggestion would be:

```
const config = { // I corrected this dev variable name
    ...,
    someRandomLink: 'https://google.com'
}

export {config}
```

```js
import {config} from '../constants/config';

...
<a href={config.someRandomLink}...
```

Notice that since you exported a method, you need then to access to that property. Otherwise, you would attempt to do something like:

```
<a href={{someRandomLink: 'myUrl.com', otherProperties: 'otherProperties'}}...
```

So that wouldn't work.

Comment: I missed an important line which shows how the config is brought in depending on a process.env